# htaccess different ExpîresByType cache control ONLY for the root of the domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I have a max-age of 3600 on the homepage and 86400 everywhere else?

Something like

```
<if URL="https://www.example.com">
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/html A3600
<else>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/html A86400
</if>
```

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples Other variables you can use, are listed above - checking `REQUEST_URI` probably makes most sense here.

Comment: Do you have any other directives in the config file? Specifically, are you rewriting the URL to a front-controller (a very common scenario these days)?

Answer (score 0):

Set the appropriate directives for the whole site and override for the root directory (homepage) only.

For example:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/html A86400
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/'">
    ExpiresByType text/html A3600
</If>
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html